# ¿Como se puede acceder a datos de un modulo usando VUEX?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Estoy tratando de utilizar los helpers de vuex para poder renderizar datos mutados en mi state (user). Cabe destacar que la peticion http se esta realizando correctamente ademas de la mutacion, lo puedo verificar llamando al state directamente mediante:

```
<p>{{$store.state.user.posts}}</p>
```

Pero yo quiero acceder a estos usando los helpers:

```
  methods:{
    ...mapState([
      'posts'
    ]),
  }
```

Si yo utilizo:

```
<p>{{posts}}</p>
```

No me renderiza ningun dato, he intentado colocar user.posts pero no pasa nada, entiendo que el problema radica en que no direcciono correctamente. Como soluciono este detalle?

Comment: El helper lo que hace es evitarte escribir el get. Pero el acceso es exactamente igual...

Comment: y entonces porque no funciona exactamente igual para renderizar? @gbianchi

Answer (score 1):

encontre la solucion al problema, este es el codigo que se utiliza para renderizar los modulos de determinado state

```
computed: mapState({
    nombreFuncion: ({moduloX}) => moduloX.propiedadState
})
```

Luego para renderizar en html:

```
<p>{{nombreFuncion.propiedadObjeto}}</p>
```